# ANTLR4 Ambiguity parsing SQL BETWEEN followed by an AND

Tags: sql, antlr4, ambiguous-grammar

I am trying to parse this expression (based on SQLite): `0 BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND 1 < 9`.

Here is the relevant portion:

```
expression
    : term #termExpression
    | left=expression '<' right=expression #lessThanExpression
    | value=expression NOT? BETWEEN lower=expression AND upper=expression #betweenExpression
    | left=expression AND right=expression #andExpression
    | left=expression OR right=expression #orExpression
    ;
```

Assume a term is a number (e.g., `0`, `1`, `2`, and `9`).

The actual SQLite parser seems to correctly parse it as so: `(0 BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AND 1 < 9`. However, my parser is treating it like `0 BETWEEN (1 AND 2) AND 1 < 9`.

[image]

What's the best way to break this ambiguity?

In SQLite, a lot is considered an "expression", including comparisons, arithmetic expressions, AND/OR/NOT, BETWEEN, etc. A boolean can validly appear in the BETWEEN range because it gets evaluated as a number (0 or 1).

There's actually many other alternatives (49 total) mapping to `expression` in the real grammar.

Answer (score 1):

There's no ambiguity. This is covered in [section 2 of the SQLite language reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Here, we see `BETWEEN` has higher precedence than `AND`, and the full operator expression is described like this:

> [expr] BETWEEN [expr] AND [expr]

Where `[expr]` is further qualified like so:

> "[expr]" denotes operand locations for **non-binary** operators

*(emphasis mine)*

Because `AND` is a binary operator, it cannot itself be part of the `BETWEEN` expression.

Therefore, the only correct interpretation is the SQLite parser, and your own parser's interpretation does not conform to the spec.

Looking at the image in the post, the flaw is `expressionandExpression` and `expressionlessThanExpression` are *not valid* in those positions, because they represent binary operators.

---

Note that other binary operators with higher precedence are allowed, because the parser will first reduce them. For example, this is okay:

```
1 BETWEEN 0 + 1 AND 2
```

...because `+` has higher precedence than `BETWEEN`, so when the `BETWEEN` expression evaluates it is already reduced to this:

```
1 BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Comment: No debate that mine is wrong.  It sounds like the solution is going to be breaking `expression` into binary and non-binary expressions and referencing the non-binary variant in BETWEEN. Sadly I read these docs over several times and totally missed the critical information.